# Select groups with more than one distinct value per group

Tags: r, subset

I have data like below:

```
ID  category class
1   a        m  
1   a        s
1   b        s
2   a        m
3   b        s
4   c        s
5   d        s
```

I want to subset the data by only including those "ID" which have several (`> 1`) different categories.

My expected output:

```
ID  category class
1   a        m
1   a        s
1   b        s
```

Is there a way to doing so?

I tried

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(category, class) > 1)
```

But it gave me an error:

```
# Error: expecting a single value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) #see: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki for more
setDT(data) #convert to native 'data.table' type by reference
data[ , if(uniqueN(category) > 1) .SD, by = ID]
```

`uniqueN` is `data.table`'s (fast) native mask for `length(unique())`, and `.SD` is just the whole `data.table` (in more general cases, it can represent a subset of columns, e.g. when the `.SDcols` argument is activated). So basically the middle statement (`j`, the column selection argument) says to return all columns and rows associated with an `ID` for which there are at least two distinct values of `category`.

Use the `by` argument to extend to a case involving counts ok multiple columns.